# Не отправляется значение из формы

Tags: php, mysql

Имеет форму:

```
 <form class="search-form" role="search" method="post"      
                            <input type="text" name="f_name" id="f_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Найти Ламера">
                            <input type="submit">
                </form>
```

и Php обработку

```
 $a=$_POST['f_name'];   
 $ame=$_SESSION['iname'];
 $hme=$ame.'#'.$a;
 $addf = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `friends`(`y_name`, `f_name`, `tag1`) VALUES ('$ame' , '$a', '$hme')");
```

Подключение к БД работает. Сессия работает. Новая запись в friends не вставляется. Что не так?\?

Comment: В форму добавить параметр action и указать в нем, где обрабатывается скрипт

Comment: И закрыть тег form